# Can I use wp_editor() to create a second instance of the editor in my post page?

Tags: wp-editor

Looking at the codex and the code they provide, it doesn't seem  like I can add a second editor. This looks like something more for front-end use rather than for use in the admin.

If I am wrong, can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to post add/edit page on admin end? Please explain little bit more for exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Inside a post page having a second content(); area other than the excerpt or custom fields(which seem to get ignored by clients, they always want formatting options in a large textarea box).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `wp_editor` on the admin end. One such situation may be by using [metabox](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box). In this case let's say you want to manage custom description about the post. So instead of a simple textarea, you can use `wp_editor`.

**Ex:**

In the example given in the above `add_meta_box` [Codex url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box), you can replace

```
echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
```

by

```
echo wp_editor( esc_attr( $value ), 'myplugin_new_field' );
```

You can try out the above code by adding into active theme's `functions.php` file. Once you do this, you should see an editor now.